# How can I use user's certificate?

Tags: java, httpclient, pem, pkcs#12

I can't understand general scheme using certificates.
For example: I have account on the some website. I have `name` and `password`. What should I do to login to this site? - I should open `_https://website:443/login` and fill out fields, and if all is ok, I'll obtain admittance.

Now, I would like to perform these steps programmatically usin java + httpclient(apache).
I've written:

```
client = new DefaultHttpClient();

client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, 
                                CookiePolicy.BEST_MATCH);
client.setCookieStore(new BasicCookieStore());
client.getCredentialsProvider()
      .setCredentials(new AuthScope(ADDRESS, new Integer(PORT)),
                      new UsernamePasswordCredentials(USERNAME, USERPWD));
```

And I should create trustStore with server's certificate:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "./KeyStore/myca");
```

where 'myca' were made with 'InstallCert.java' - Sun's product.

But I would like to perform all this steps programmatically, like Browser(FFox, or Opera) import server's certificate...User just want to use only my application, not a set of additional application.

How can I do perform it?

And now, the main problem: why do servers not require user's certificate? And how do I can use my own certificate to authenticate? (If I have user's certificate I will not need 'name''password' to login to server?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why do servers not require user's
>   certificate?

Servers do not require user certificates, because most users don't have one, don't now what it is and how to get one. And even if they would, such a certificate is either difficult or expensive to obtain, so many user won't get one.

So any server requiring a client certificate would reduce the number of users probably by a factor of 1000. Most server owners don't want that.

> If I have user's certificate I will
>   not need 'name''password' to login to
>   server?

Depends on your requirements. Requiring a certificate + username/password would be considered a two factor authentication, which is a stronger form of protection, then just requiring one factor. It would get even stronger by asking for some kind of biometric identification.

> How can I do perform it?

Perform exactly what? You are talking about doing things "programmatically", but you already present code ...?

> And how do I can use my own certificate to authenticate?

This should be done in the configuration of your server. You need to setup a trust store containing the trustet root certificates + require client authenticatication in the ssl configuration. e.g search [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) for clientauth.